# Java Web Service JAX WS Tool

Tags: java, jdbc, jax-ws

I have created the web service and in that i am coonecting the database and access the information form that but couldn't successful.

/

```
**
 * 
 */
package com.xxxxx.www.testprocess;
import javax.jws.*;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * @author Suryasol6
 *
 */
@WebService(name="TestProcess",targetNamespace ="http://www.example.org/TestProcess")
public class TestProcess {
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement ps = null;
    private ResultSet rs = null;
    private static final String CONNECTION_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/java_test?user=root&;password=";

    @WebMethod(action="http://www.example.org/TestProcess/TestLogin")
    @WebResult(name="TestLoginresponse")
    public String TestLogin(@WebParam(name="name")
            String name,@WebParam(name="password")
            String password)
    {
        try
            {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                return "fail here";
            }
        return "pass";
    }

}
```

I can publish the web service but when i try to connect the web service with parametes, it fails to load the jdbc driver.

But when i try to run this file as seperate this worked.

Can anybody help me??

Comment: what is the exception stacktrace?

Comment: I am deploying on Jboss AS 6.0.1.

Comment: Please add the cause in the post with proper format

Comment: `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from BaseClassLoader@1ad54ea{vfs:///E:/Workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1323032758082/deploy/TestEAR2.ear/Test2.war/}`

Comment: Please add the stacktrace in question this doesn't give any information that helps to fix your issue

Comment: I didnt get any stacktrace. All things are working are fine except while loading the driver. I am testing this service from SOAP UI. When i test this service to process anything which are apart from database it actually works successfully.

Comment: you can have stack trace vt modifying your catch statement as `catch(Exception e){
            {e.printstacktrace();
                return "fail here";
            }`

Comment: Thanks for the stacktrace. It was the library problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the MySQL driver jar in the JBoss server lib directory?  It should go in:

```
<JBoss_home>/server/default/lib
```

When you run it manually you may be specifying the classpath to include the jar, but JBoss needs it there.